# How do I loop text comparing code through my entire worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am comparing two cells (A1 and B1) with nearly identical text and want to highlight the text that is different in C1. I have found code that accomplishes comparing just the two cells, but having trouble looping it through my entire sheet. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
Sub CompareInColor()

    ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    
    For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
        If (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I hope by entire worksheet you mean all values in column `A`. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

### Compare Characters

- Try to access the worksheet as few times as possible. The efficiency can still be improved e.g., by using an array.

**Range Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareInColor()

    With ActiveSheet ' With Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1") ' is safer.
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim CurrLen As Long
        Dim Remainder As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim str2 As String
        
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            
            str1 = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            str2 = .Cells(i, "B").Value
            
            If Len(str1) < Len(str2) Then
                CurrLen = Len(str1)
                Remainder = 0
            Else
                CurrLen = Len(str2)
                Remainder = Len(str1) - CurrLen
            End If
            
            Set cel = .Cells(i, "C")
            cel.Value = str1
            
            For j = 1 To CurrLen
                If Mid(str1, j, 1) <> Mid(str2, j, 1) Then
                    cel.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next j
            
            If Remainder > 0 Then
                For j = CurrLen + 1 To CurrLen + 1 + Remainder
                    cel.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Next j
            End If
        
        Next i
        
    End With

End Sub
```

**Array Version**

```
Sub CompareInColorArray()

    With ActiveSheet ' With Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1") ' is safer.
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim Data As Variant
        Data = .Cells(1, "A").Resize(LastRow, 2)
        
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim CurrLen As Long
        Dim Remainder As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim str2 As String
        
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            
            str1 = Data(i, 1)
            str2 = Data(i, 2)
            
            If Len(str1) < Len(str2) Then
                CurrLen = Len(str1)
                Remainder = 0
            Else
                CurrLen = Len(str2)
                Remainder = Len(str1) - CurrLen
            End If
            
            Set cel = .Cells(i, "C")
            cel.Value = str1
            
            For j = 1 To CurrLen
                If Mid(str1, j, 1) <> Mid(str2, j, 1) Then
                    cel.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next j
            
            If Remainder > 0 Then
                For j = CurrLen + 1 To CurrLen + 1 + Remainder
                    cel.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Next j
            End If
        
        Next i
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- You need to change the references to static cells to be dynamic
- A loop needs to be added to cycle through cells in column "A"
- Also need to move the line that transfers the value from column "A" into the loop

This should do the trick:

```
Sub CompareInColor()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    
        For c = 1 To Len(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
            If (ws.Cells(i, 1).Characters(c, 1).Text <> ws.Cells(i, 2).Characters(c, 1).Text) Then
                ws.Cells(i, 3).Characters(c, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next c
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning, if you want this loop to run through **ALL** rows in column "A", then you'll need to change: `For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to: `For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`. The code provided in my answer finds the last row with a value in column "A"

Comment: This is great! but it doesn't factor the characters that are identical. My previous code would only change the font color within the text as soon as the characters misaligned. Adding characters code doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Apologies, it seems I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to show the correct code now, although as @VBasic2008 has mentioned this is probably not the most efficient way of tackling this problem (I just tried to keep the code as similar as possible to what you started with), if you are having trouble with efficiency then it might be worth trying to implement one of VBasic2008's answers